# interactive docker build from dockerfile?

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I want to use a Dockerfile to build an image. However, commands will need user input as they run. Currently, the build is not successful because docker exits on user input. I know I can use the -i -t options on docker run command but I want to do that on a Dockerfile. How is that possible?

Comment: It depends on what userinput, if it's userinput for apt-get update as example, then you can add -y to always say yes. Otherwise, run something that takes userinput, save it in an environment variable and then pull it from the environment variables.

Comment: I am running 'rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module'. I am not sure your recommendation applies here.

Comment: In that case I would build a base image with those modules already installed (manually entering the needed data), then create Dockerfiles using that new image. I'm curious to see if there's a generic way to solve it if the script you're running doesn't support unattended setup ...

Comment: Depending on what command needs user input they are ways to get around it, for instance to set the password 'f00' for user 'bar' you could add to the Dockerfile: RUN echo 'bar:f00' | chpasswd

Answer (score 7):

You can try with [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) or a similar tool.

The easiest way to configure it is using the `autoexpect` tool, which lets you run the commands interactively and creates an expect script for you.

I couldn't get the rvmsudo stuff working (I haven't used it and didn't want to spend too much time with it) so I decided to use `vi` instead. First run `autoexpect`

```
$ autoexpect vi test
```

This will open `vi` and you can create or edit the file and save it. After exiting the `vi` you'll see your file `test` as well as an expect script `script.exp`.

You can then remove the test file and execute `script.exp`. It will recreate the same file using the same steps.

The autoexpect tool is great, but you may have to create a script from scratch if you need to have more control over what happens. E.g. if you don't want the script to work with the exact expected input.

Comment: Gotta love downvoters, who don't comment on what's wrong with he answer. Cheers to you!